# How can i display a process StandardOutput in textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 constructor

```
cmd = " -i \"" + InputFile + "\" \"" + OutputFile + "\"";
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then

```
private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text = line;
            }
        }
```

Then in dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertNow(cmd);
        }
```

The problem is in the ConvertNow method in the line:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
```

I used a break point and it's getting to the while but then the program hang after this line it's never get in to the string and the textBox lines.

How can i make that it will displat the output maybe in the textBox or maybe in a nicer control make richTextBox or maybe something else ?

This is what i tried now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConvertVideo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string InputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909.MOV";
        string OutputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909.mp4";
        string cmd;
        string exepath = @"E:\myffmpegstatic\ffmpeg-20151217-git-9d1fb9e-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
        FileInfo fi;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => textBox1.AppendText((string)e.UserState);
            fi = new FileInfo(InputFile);
            label2.Text = InputFile;
            cmd = " -i \"" + InputFile + "\" \"" + OutputFile + "\"";
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                // use this event
                proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, e.Data); // use this for synchronization

                proc.Start();

                // and start asynchronous read
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

                // wait until it's finished in your background worker thread
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string myerr = err.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertNow(cmd);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i use a breakpoint on the line:

```
proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, e.Data);
```

And put my mouse over proc i see inside that all the properties with the same exception:

BasePriority = 'proc.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Almost all the properties like that.
Tried to add try and catch around but it's not getting to the catch.

Comment: Where do you declare "backgroundWorker1"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code. The worst: you try to update a control from a different thread than the UI thread.

I suggest you change your `ConvertNow` method to the following:

```
private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    // use this event
    proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, e.Data); // use this for synchronization

    proc.Start();

    // and start asynchronous read
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // wait until it's finished in your background worker thread
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Add a `ProgressChanged` event to your background worker (e.g. in the form constructor):

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => textBox1.AppendText((string)e.UserState);
```

So now, whenever your process writes to stdout, you get an event that is invoked on the UI thread and appends the data to your text box.

**UPDATE**: If you already have an handler for `backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged` you don't need to add another but can insert the line `textBox1.AppendText((string)e.UserState);` in your handler directly. But if you call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress` from other parts as mine you should first check if `e.UserState` is actually a string that should be added to the textBox.

Comment: Can't spot the error, it's working fine for me here. Maybe it's a problem with the binary you are starting for your process? Does it output something to stdout at all? Maybe it uses stderr? (btw: let's clean these comments, this shouldn't be a chat)

Comment: I tested now i see in the line: proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, e.Data); error on all properties:  StandardOutput = 'proc.StandardOutput' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' Same exception error on all properties of proc

Comment: Ok let me add just once again my code in the question as it is now. I will add that in the designer in the backgroundworker i removed the progresschanged event there and i only register to it through the constructor using your line so there will be no mistakes.